# How to clone a git repository that requires clean/smudge filter?

Tags: git

My repo `https://example.com/repo.git` requires a smudge and clean filter. I try the following to get set up before.

```
$ git init --bare
$ git config filter.example.required true
$ git config filter.example.smudge "/path/to/smudge-filter.sh %f"
$ git config filter.example.clean "/path/to/clean-filter.sh %f"
$ git remote add master https://example.com/repo.git
$ git pull
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Or is it the other way round? Clone the repo and apply the filter after the effect?

Comment: `git init --bare` creates a bare repository, which has no working tree. `git pull` needs working tree. You can remove `--bare` to create a normal repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is to clone but checkout later:

```
$ git clone --no-checkout https://example.com/repo.git
$ git config filter.example.required true
$ git config filter.example.smudge "/path/to/smudge-filter.sh %f"
$ git config filter.example.clean "/path/to/clean-filter.sh %f"
$ git checkout --
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? Seems like a viable solution to me?

Comment: If the filter files are saved in the repository itself, for any other team member to use, I get the following error with `clone --no-checkout`: `error: cannot spawn smudge-filter.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: I also had that problem but never found a way round it.